# Get time until local time is N hours from now, taking summer-time changes into account

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, timezone

Timezones and summer-time changes in particular confuse me. In the UK we have GMT/BST:

> In the UK the clocks go forward 1 hour at 1am on the last Sunday in
>   March, and back 1 hour at 2am on the last Sunday in October. The
>   period when the clocks are 1 hour ahead is called British Summer Time
>   (BST).

Given a local time say 00:00 I want to be able to calculate how long until it is 03:00 in local time. Normally this is trivially 3 hours but on March 26th (last Sunday in March) from 00:00 - 03:00 is actually *two* hours. And similarly when the clocks go back in October from 00:00 - 03:00 is *four* hours.

Do the .Net DateTime class and its methods do this trivially for me or do I need to be careful?

In my case specifically I'm working from strings so I'm after a method doing:

```
TimeSpan DifferenceBetweenLocalTimes(string startDateTime,string endDateTime)
```

I can see things like `TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime` but how to use this to do as I wish is not obvious. My application works treating each calendar day's local midnight as a strict boundary i.e. not every day is 24 hours long, once a year I get a 23 hour day and a 25 hour day.

Comment: As a side-question... if I have `endDateTime = 26/3/2017 01:30` what happens given the clocks jump from 01:00 -> 02:00 on this date? Does this time even exist?!

Comment: Well you can answer that one for yourself.. the  answer is yes the time exsits, and no .net doesnt do daylight saving for you, and different timezones do them at different times of the year. You might be able to do the time differnce if you have the timezone in the time.

Comment: So the DST changes are driven directly by Windows changing the time-zone, and .Net is ignorant of that? i.e. it works exactly as if I manually change the time-zone in my Control Panel at those two times?

Comment: You could do all your logic processing using UTC and only localize on output?

Comment: @ChrisPickford I'm not sure how that would work when I'm working with midnight as my strict boundary; once a year, my day is 23 hours long and once a year it is 25 hours... wouldn't working in Utc hide that?

Comment: @BugFinder if that's the case why does `TimeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime` exist? Surely .Net _does_ know about DST changes... so confusing!

Answer (score 4):

You can use `TimeZoneInfo` class to get the offset from your local date time to UTC (including daylight tricks). For example

```
var timeZone =TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");
var date1 = DateTime.Parse("2017-03-26 00:00:00");
var date2 = DateTime.Parse("2017-03-26 03:00:00");
var dto1 = new DateTimeOffset(date1, timeZone.GetUtcOffset(date1));
var dto2 = new DateTimeOffset(date2, timeZone.GetUtcOffset(date2));

var diff1 = (dto2 - dto1).TotalHours;

Console.WriteLine(diff1); // this is 2 hours
```

The `GetUtcOffset` method returns difference between time in that time zone and UTC

Comment: Minor nitpick - you can find that zone with "TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("GMT Standard Time");"

Comment: And trivially I can just call `DateTime.Parse(...)` to get suitable `date1` & `date2` values... no `DateTimeKind` messiness?

Comment: @Mr.Boy it depends on target string. For example if you do this `var test = DateTime.Parse("2017-03-26 03:00:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` the resulting DateTime will have kind Unspecified which is just what you need. However, if you do this: `DateTime.Parse("2017-03-26 03:00:00 +01:00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` - the result will have kind Local (and will indeed represent time in your local zone) - that is not what you need.

Comment: @Mr.Boy yes you can, it produces date time with `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` (assuming there is no time zone component in the string). Code updated again

Answer (score 0):

While [tchrikch's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43202726/get-time-until-local-time-is-n-hours-from-now-taking-summer-time-changes-into-a#43203169) is perfectly reasonable (and should be accepted, IMHO), it's worth adding a [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) based solution.

```
// Parse input as LocalDateTime values (since they represent a local date and time)
var pattern = LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
LocalDateTime ldt1 = pattern.Parse("2017-03-26 00:00:00").Value;
LocalDateTime ldt2 = pattern.Parse("2017-03-26 03:00:00").Value;

// Apply a specific time zone, now making them ZonedDateTime values
// Using "lenient" conversions allows for default handling of ambiguous/invalid values
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/London"];
ZonedDateTime zdt1 = ldt1.InZoneLeniently(tz);
ZonedDateTime zdt2 = ldt2.InZoneLeniently(tz);

// Now simply determine the elapsed duration between these
Duration result = zdt2 - zdt1;
```

Note that the subtraction between `ZonedDateTime` values was added in NodaTime 2.0.  If you're on an older version, you'll need to do this instead:

```
Duration result = zdt2.ToInstant() - zdt1.ToInstant();
```